# Xamarin.Form.Android EntryRenderer.OnFocusChanged never called

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I had created a WEntryRenderer which derives from EntryRenderer. My problem is simple I had overridden the OnFocusChanged method from EntryRenderer cause I want to stop focus propagation if something goes wrong. The problem is that this method is never called. I don't understand why, does any one has the answer for me please?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Renderer Android pour le contrôl WEntry
    /// </summary>
    public class WEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnFocusChanged(bool gainFocus, [GeneratedEnum] FocusSearchDirection direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect)
        {
            bool dontSetFocus = false;

            //if (Something goes wrong)
            //{
            //    dontSetFocus = true;
            //}

            if (!dontSetFocus)
            {
                base.OnFocusChanged(gainFocus, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
            }
        }
}
```

**Here is an alternative solution :**

```
//Branching the event

        private void SubscribeEvents()
        {
            //Emit au changement de focus
            this.Control.FocusChange += WEntryRenderer_FocusChanged;
        }


//Code related

        private void WEntryRenderer_FocusChanged(object sender, FocusChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            //Si on perd le focus, on emet l'événement PropertyValidated de la propriété lié au composant
            if (!e.HasFocus && wentryRequiringFocus == null)
            {
                //Emet l'événementValidated
                this.currentWEntry.ModelPropertyBinding.OnPropertyValidated();

                //Si le composant possède des erreur et qu'aucune requête de focus n'est en cours, le composant requiert le focus
                if (!ListManager.IsNullOrEmpty(this.currentWEntry.ErrorList))
                {
                    //Place le focus sur le control courant
                    this.currentWEntry.Focus();

                    //On indique à la classe que le focus est demandé par cette instance
                    WEntryRenderer.wentryRequiringFocus = this.currentWEntry;
                }
            }
            //Si le focus a été demandé  par l'instance courante, on libère la demande à la récupération du focus
            else if (e.HasFocus && WEntryRenderer.wentryRequiringFocus == this.currentWEntry)
            {
                //Libère la requête de focus
                WEntryRenderer.wentryRequiringFocus = null;
            }
        }
```

I don;t like this solution cause even if you force the focus on the actual instance, the focus is already set to another view... It cause a lot of problems within ListView

Answer (score 0):

Did you decorate it with the correct assembly attribute?

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (Entry), typeof (WEntryRenderer))]
namespace YourProject.iOS
{

...

}
```

This is needed to instruct Xamarin Forms that this renderer needs to be called for the type (`Entry`) specified as the first parameter.

**UPDATE:**

An alternative solution can try is to check in your `OnElementPropertyChanged` for the `IsFocused` property:

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

    if (e.PropertyName == "IsFocused")
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your awnser :) Yes i did. Everything but this method works perfectly fine. I have a OnElementPropertyChanged, OnElementChanged that wokrs... but this OnFocusChange is never called =(

Comment: I updated with an alternative solution you could try.

Comment: I added some more informations :). With your solution the focus would be set etherway =/ I want to stop a FocusSet.

Comment: @Equissx, please elaborate a bit more, I don't get what you mean.